# Typescript spread in function type definition

Tags: typescript, typing

I want to create a Typescript function which takes any other function and a list of arguments and calls the given function with the given arguments. For example:

```
function thisDoesSomething(arg1: string, arg2: int) {
    // do something
}
callMyFunction(thisDoesSomething, "a string", 7);
```

For the definition of the function, I tried something along the lines of:

```
function callMyFunction<T>(toCall: (...T) => any, ...args: T) {
    toCall(...args);
}
```

However, this of course does not work. Is there any way to achieve my goal in typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close, you can do this in Typescript 3.0 using [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).

```
function callMyFunction<T extends unknown[]>(toCall: (...a: T) => any, ...args: T) {
    toCall(...args);
}

function thisDoesSomething(arg1: string, arg2: number) {
    // do something
}
callMyFunction(thisDoesSomething, "a string", 7);
callMyFunction(thisDoesSomething, "a string", "7"); // error
```

There were just two issues with your code, firstly `T` has to extend an array type, secondly the argument to `toCall` must have a name, the way you were declaring it `toCall` had a parameter named `T` implicitly of type `any`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function callMyFunction<T extends any[]>(toCall: (...T) => any, ...args: T) {
    return toCall(...args);
}
```

Or even simpler without generic types

```
function callMyFunction(toCall: Function, ...args: any[]) {
    return toCall(...args);
}
```

There are also the function prototype methods `call` and `apply` that you can use, like this:

```
//call:
thisDoesSomething.call(this, "a string", 7);
//apply:
thisDoesSomething.apply(this, ["a string", 7]);
```